# Symfony cloud MPDF temp files can't be stored in /tmp

Tags: mpdf

Our project is going to be on Linux, and we want to have the temp files be stored in /tmp/mpdf. I have the following MPDF constructor:

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf(['mode' => 'en',
    'default_font_size' => 8,
    'margin_left' => 9.5,
    'margin_right' => 0,
    'margin_bottom' => 37,
    'margin_header' => 0,
    'margin_footer' => 2,
    'fontDir' => array_merge((new ConfigVariables())->getDefaults()['fontDir'], [realpath(getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT')) . '/../assets/fonts']),
    'fontdata' => (new FontVariables())->getDefaults()['fontdata'] + [
        'arialuni' => [
            'R' => 'arialuni.ttf',
            'B' => 'arialuni.ttf'
        ]
    ],
    'tempDir' => sys_get_temp_dir()
]);
```

However, I end up getting the following error:

```
"[prod] Feb 26 10:40:30 |CRITICA| REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception Mpdf\MpdfException: "Temporary files directory "/app/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Config/../../tmp/mpdf" is not writable" at /app/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Cache.php line 21"
```

From what I understand, it still tries to use the following folder:

```
/app/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp/mpdf
```

It should however use the /tmp folder which was recommended by the symfony cloud support (the /tmp folder of Linux)

Comment: Show more complete code and the whole error message, this is hardly enough information. You probably have an error somewhere, this setting should work as you expect.

Comment: I'm sorry I didnt realize I didnt copy the full error, should be good now

Comment: What if you hardcode `/tmp` as `tempDir` manually? Are you really using this particular instance of mPDF?

Comment: Even if I use /tmp I get the same issue. How do you mean the last question? That's the constructor i use yeah

Comment: Can you dump what is passed to to the constructor of Mpdf\Cache class? What is your mPDF version? I tried locally and the cache with `'tempDir' => sys_get_temp_dir()` is saved to `/tmp/mpdf`.

Comment: Provide a complete backtrace of the error in question. Also, what are permissions for /app/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp/mpdf, that it is not writable? The directory should be made writable by composer post-install-cmd.

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same issue recently and it is caused by the Mpdf library not having enough permission to write to the vendors folder, (which frankly it shouldn't have).
The solution for me was to update the tmp_dir in ConfigVariables.php to use PHP's temp dir instead of the one it tries to use.

Made a fork => https://packagist.org/packages/tevli/mpdf

Github => https://github.com/tevli/mpdf

Comment: It would be great if you could share here the code snippet

Comment: in ConfigVariables.php, set  `'tempDir' => sys_get_temp_dir(),`